# Sound Design: How would you create this pluck?

Tags: sound-design, ableton-live, synthesis, replication

I'm trying to create a pluck similar to the one that starts at 00:48 secs

https://soundcloud.com/r3hab/john-legend-you-and-i-r3hab-remix

I'm using a square wave with short attack, short decay, long sustain, short release and a pitch envelope (zero attack, very short decay, very short sustain, zero release). I would then layer the pluck with some saws and some white noise.

Any hint? How would you create it?

Another similar example could be the one used in this track:

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This article has some interesting theoretical discussion about synthesizing string sounds!  http://www.soundonsound.com/sos/Aug01/articles/synthsecrets28.asp

Of course you aren't going after the plucking of a real acoustic guitar but there are some rules of thumb in there that may help you distinguish your sound as more of a pluck and less of a blip that may share a similar ADSR envelope.

One thing I believe helps is harmonics. A simple modeled string being plucked near the center will produce mostly odd number intervals in the overtone series - that is, the fundamental, three times the fundamental, five times the fundamental, etc.  If you start off with sine waves weighted at these intervals, then experiment with different waveforms and noise to add bite and color, you are pretty much guaranteed to get a "plucky" sound.

All that said, I like Ableton's "Tension" modeling instrument for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Many things could replicate this effect:

May I suggest some of the following:

1. You could use a bow. Yes as in a bow and arrow. This would create a cool boiiing plucking effect.
2. You could some elastic bands. If you wanted a long noise let them vibrate otherwise pull them back on a hard surface.

Hope this helps.